# Cocos2D: Recognize multiple tiles next to each other

Tags: cocos2d-x, tiles, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I'm currently building a platformer in cocos2d-x and therefore i'm using a tmxtiledmap and chipmunk physics. My problem is that in the moment EACH tile of the map gets its own physics body which obviously isnt really memory saving:D
Is there any method to "recognize" that multiple tiles are next to each other and therefore only need one physics body?

Greets FreezZl

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the physics bodies?I dont use chipmunk, but had used box2d with Tiled and created a single Physics body for each platform by assigning an object to the whole platform in tiled and using that to create the physics body.

Comment: Well until now i looped through every single tile and assigned a body to each of them:'D But your idea sounds awesome, going to try that! Big thank you!

Comment: Your welcome and in that case, please accept the answer :P